# I'm trying to extract the data from links within a website through scrapy and getting an error in code

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to extract the data from the links within a website. The Path I'm following is:

Home page

-links

-links

- data to be extracted (Basically, I'm trying to extract all the birth_details of famous celebrities)

My scrapy code is as follows:

```
    import scrapy
    class celebritiesItem(scrapy.Item):

           Name = scrapy.Field()
           Profession = scrapy.Field()
           Died_On = scrapy.Field()
           Birth_Place = scrapy.Field()
           Nationality = scrapy.Field()
           Birth_Date = scrapy.Field()

    class celebrities(scrapy.Spider):
          name = "people"
          allowed_domains = ["thefamouspeople.com"]
          start_urls = [
         "http://www.thefamouspeople.com/famous-people-by-birthday.php"
          ]

          def parse(self, response):

          links = response.xpath('//div[@class="pod colorbar 
          editorial"]//@href').extract()
          for link in links:
               abs_url = response.xpath('//div[@class="pod colorbar 
               editorial"]//@href').extract()
           yield scrapy.Request(abs_url, callback=self.parse)

          #items[]
          item = celebritiesItem()
          item["Name"] = 
          response.xpath('//div[@class="section"]//a[2]//text()').extract()
          item["Profession"] = 
          response.xpath('//div[@class="section"]//span//text()').extract()
          item["Died_On"] = 
          response.xpath('//div[@class="section"]//p[1]//text()').extract()
          item["Birth_Place"] = 
          response.xpath('//div[@class="section"]//p[2]//text()').extract()
          item["Nationality"] = 
          response.xpath('//div[@class="section"]//p[3]//text()').extract()
          item["Birth_Date"] = 
          response.xpath('//div[@class="section"]//p[4]//text()').extract()
          yield item
```

and I'm getting the following error:

raise TypeError('Request url must be str or unicode, got %s:' % type(url).**name**)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error results from this part

```
      for link in links:
           abs_url = response.xpath('//div[@class="pod colorbar 
           editorial"]//@href').extract()
       yield scrapy.Request(abs_url, callback=self.parse)
```

You need to indent the yield statement and create a proper url

```
      for link in links:
           abs_url = response.urljoin(link)
           yield scrapy.Request(abs_url, callback=self.parse)
```

Comment: It worked.. though i was not getting the data in the proper format, so I used extract_first() instead of extract(). :)